multiprocessing doesn't clear cache
I am trying to use multiprocessing to optimize some calculations. The code to start it looks something like this:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    params = list(itertools.product(cutoff_hours, cutoff_minutes, chunk_sizes, buffer_sizes, products, optimize_ons))

    params_dilled = [dill.dumps(param) for param in params]

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20, initializer=worker_init, maxtasksperchild=10) as pool:
        results = pool.map(compute_for_parameters, params_dilled)

where:
def worker_init():
    globals()["dill"] = dill

and:
def compute_for_parameters(params_dilled):
    try:
        params = dill.loads(params_dilled)

        var1, var2, var3 = params

        try:
            starter = StarterClass(
                var1=var1,
                var2=var2,
                var3=var3,
            )

            results = starter.get_data()

            return results
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error processing parameters {params}: {e}")
            raise
    finally:
        logger.info(f"Clearing cache...")
        del pnl, results
        gc.collect()

Each instance of StarterClass loads some data (unfortunately a lot), which probably equates to roughly 500MB in size.
My issue is, that in the beginning, everything is doing fine. It loads, calculates, and goes on to the next. But as the multiprocessing progresses, I can see more and more data is being cached in memory, and eventually it just ends up being all my RAM used for caching, and everything just halts or becomes crazy slow.
How do I circumvent, or at least clear my cache whenever a process is done ?
The:
finally:
    logger.info(f"Clearing cache...")
    del pnl, results
    gc.collect()

doesn't seem to do much. Also, results doesn't take up much size, so even though it's saving that, that shouldn't be the cause of concern.
Or do I need some kind of other approach for this ?

There's no need for del pnl, results when a function returns. All its local variables get deleted automatically. If the memory isn't clearning, something else must have references to that data, the references from the variables are irrelevant.

I suggest you look into how StarterClass works, it may be saving the data somewhere.
